# Cannot use -tagPath and schema at the same time in PigStorage LOAD

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm having an interesting behaviour with `PigStorage` and its `-tagPath` option, where I do not know if I am doing something wrong (wrong schema definition?) or if this is a limitation/bug in Pig.

My file looks like this (the most basic, I was able to come up with):

```
A
B
```

Now I can load and subselect this file like this fine:

```
vals = LOAD '/user/guest/test.txt'
    USING PigStorage(';') AS (char: chararray);

DUMP vals

one_column = FOREACH vals GENERATE char;

DUMP one_column
```

Results in:

```
(A)
(B)
(A)
(B)
```

However, when I try to fetch the filepath with `-tagPath` (I need it when I access a whole folder of data), the data gets loaded correctly into the first variable, but I cannot subselect a column from it.

```
vals = LOAD '/user/guest/test.txt'
    USING PigStorage(';', '-tagPath')
    AS (filepath: chararray, char: chararray);

DUMP vals

one_column = FOREACH vals GENERATE char;

DUMP one_column
```

Results in:

```
(hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/user/guest/test.txt,A)
(hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/user/guest/test.txt,B)
(hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/user/guest/test.txt)
(hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/user/guest/test.txt)
```

However, when I first read the data without schema and then add a schema using `FOREACH` it works fine again:

```
vals = LOAD '/user/guest/test.txt'
    USING PigStorage(';', '-tagPath');

vals_n = FOREACH vals GENERATE (chararray)$0 AS filepath, (chararray)$1 AS char;

DUMP vals_n

one_column = FOREACH vals GENERATE char;

DUMP one_column
```

Results in:

```
(hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/user/guest/test.txt,A)
(hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/user/guest/test.txt,B)
(A)
(B)
```

So is there any way, I can use `-tagPath` and schema in the `LOAD` phase at the same time?

Comment: This looks weird , I am noticing same result too. I checked the Java Class for PigStorage. It sends the  src_path with the schema in return. Though tagPath is deprecated and tagFile is replaced with latest versions. tagFile has the same behaviour as well. I am interested in know the reason. Did you raise this as a pig issue ?

Comment: No, haven't yet. Since I am a pig newcomer, I didn't know if I was wrong. So I'll check that from office tomorrow.

Comment: Do post the answer here, if you get any.Thanks !

Comment: Haven't tested yet, but here seems to be a solution: http://www.webopius.com/content/764/resolved-apache-pig-with-tagsource-tagfile-option-generates-incorrect-columns

Comment: I tried it . And Yeah , its working .

Answer (score 0):

This happens, because pig tries to find out automatically which columns are being used in the script and only load those. When we use `-tagFile` or `-tagPath`, it seems this gets confused.

The solution is to [run the pig script without this column detection](http://www.webopius.com/content/764/resolved-apache-pig-with-tagsource-tagfile-option-generates-incorrect-columns):

```
pig -x mapreduce -t ColumnMapKeyPrune
```